# How to remove the <p> tags in CMS pages using {{block type="core/template" template="file.phtml"}}

Tags: template, cms

In Magento 1.9, I am creating CMS pages. I have a CMS page that fires an external template:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="/modules/storelocator/storelocator.phtml"}}
```

However, this page has this code

```
Hello World
```

When Magento is accessed this page, it fires and nests

tags inside everything. Can this be removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You need to turn the static block WYSIWYG editor off-by-default.**

Content Management tab in system configuration.

Then edit your static blocks carefully - use the WYSIWYG but check your HTML afterwards.

for detail you can see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345987/magento-static-blocks-remove-wrapping-p)

Answer (score 1):

This

possible to removed,just click on  and remove predefined p tag  and put code  your code.

`{{block type="core/template" template="/modules/storelocator/storelocator.phtml"}`}

### Better to use layout handler

**Better idea to go design tab  of  that Cms  pages   and put your block as your content block of this page:**

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="core/template" template="/modules/storelocator/storelocator.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually easy to do, I just implemented it in my own custom module without modifying any core js files.

In the layout xml file for my module, I added this:

```
<reference name="js">
  <block type="adminhtml/template" name="js.wysiwyg.setup" template="inventory/js/wysiwyg/setup.phtml" />
</reference>
```

My module is named Inventory so i added the folder to my module's admin template file structure at inventory/js/wysiwyg/setup.phtml

In this file, I simply copied the "getSettings" method from js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js and redefined that method in my newly created file at inventory/js/wysiwyg/setup.phtml. Like so:

```
<script>
 // THIS IS HOW WE OVERRIDE MAGENTO'S WYSIWYG SETTINGS 
 // ADVICE FOR THE ACTUAL SETTINGS THAT I CHANGED BELOW CAME FROM 
 // http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/06/overcoming-magentos-wysiwyg-part-2-customizing-tinymce-settings

 // THIS IS A SIMPLE REDEFINING OF THE FUNCTION. SEE MY COMMENT BELOW TO SEE THE ONLY 3 LINES I HAD TO ADD

 tinyMceWysiwygSetup.prototype.getSettings = function(mode){
        var plugins = 'safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,advhr,advimage,emotions,iespell,media,searchreplace,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras';

        if (this.config.widget_plugin_src) {
            plugins = 'magentowidget,' + plugins;
        }

        var magentoPluginsOptions = $H({});
        var magentoPlugins = '';

        if (this.config.plugins) {
            (this.config.plugins).each(function(plugin){
                magentoPlugins = plugin.name + ',' + magentoPlugins;
                magentoPluginsOptions.set(plugin.name, plugin.options);
            });
            if (magentoPlugins) {
                plugins = '-' + magentoPlugins + plugins;
            }
        }

        var settings = {
            mode : (mode != undefined ? mode : 'none'),
            elements : this.id,
            theme : 'advanced',
            plugins : plugins,
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : magentoPlugins + 'magentowidget,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect',
            theme_advanced_buttons2 : 'cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,forecolor,backcolor',
            theme_advanced_buttons3 : 'tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,iespell,media,advhr,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen',
            theme_advanced_buttons4 : 'insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,pagebreak',
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : 'top',
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : 'left',
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location : 'bottom',
            theme_advanced_resizing : true,

            // THESE 3 LINES ARE ALL I ADDED TO THE FUNCTION
            extended_valid_elements : '+div[*],+span[*],+a[*],+link[*],+script[*]',
            valid_children : '+a[h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|p|span|div|img]',
            forced_root_block : false,

            convert_urls : false,
            relative_urls : false,
            content_css: this.config.content_css,
            custom_popup_css: this.config.popup_css,
            magentowidget_url: this.config.widget_window_url,
            magentoPluginsOptions: magentoPluginsOptions,
            doctype : '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">',

            setup : function(ed) {
                ed.onSubmit.add(function(ed, e) {
                    varienGlobalEvents.fireEvent('tinymceSubmit', e);
                });

                ed.onPaste.add(function(ed, e, o) {
                    varienGlobalEvents.fireEvent('tinymcePaste', o);
                });

                ed.onBeforeSetContent.add(function(ed, o) {
                    varienGlobalEvents.fireEvent('tinymceBeforeSetContent', o);
                });

                ed.onSetContent.add(function(ed, o) {
                    varienGlobalEvents.fireEvent('tinymceSetContent', o);
                });

                ed.onSaveContent.add(function(ed, o) {
                    varienGlobalEvents.fireEvent('tinymceSaveContent', o);
                });

                ed.onChange.add(function(ed, l) {
                    varienGlobalEvents.fireEvent('tinymceChange', l);
                });

                ed.onExecCommand.add(function(ed, cmd, ui, val) {
                    varienGlobalEvents.fireEvent('tinymceExecCommand', cmd);
                });
            }
        };

        // Set the document base URL
        if (this.config.document_base_url) {
            settings.document_base_url = this.config.document_base_url;
        }

        if (this.config.files_browser_window_url) {
            settings.file_browser_callback = function(fieldName, url, objectType, w) {
                varienGlobalEvents.fireEvent("open_browser_callback", {win:w, type:objectType, field:fieldName});
            };
        }

        if (this.config.width) {
            settings.width = this.config.width;
        }

        if (this.config.height) {
            settings.height = this.config.height;
        }

        return settings;     
 };
</script>
```